# Issues using krpano Created Html Run locally in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I am working on a panaroma application where I am using Krpano generated html file.
When I run the  file in online it work properly But When I saved the folder in local and try to run offline It runs on simulator but in iPhone or iPad device showing Black screen.
What should I do ? Any Solution Please suggest ...

Comment: I have the same problem did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to upload your krpano gallery to a free webspace, the krpano viewer only runs on the krpano testing server when you are offline. but there is no ipad version of the testing server, so the only solution is to go online with the pano.